# Gmail search with API and access token

Tags: http, google-api, gmail, gmail-api

I am trying to fetch Gmail search results from Gmail API using an access token.

The following code works and returns an array of my email IDs:

```
fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/${userId}/messages?access_token=${accessToken}`)
```

I then try to append a search query following the [Gmail API documentation guidelines](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list)

```
fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/${userId}/messages?access_token=${accessToken}?q=${text}`)
```

and it brings this error `code: 401, message: 'Invalid Credentials'`

Authentication scope is set to `https://mail.google.com/` which assumes full control of the email. I tried swapping `access_token` and `q` parameters, as well as removing the `access_token` parameter but still no success. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/${userId}/messages?access_token=${accessToken}?q=${text}

you are preforming a HTTP GET in this call.  Additional parameters are tacked on using a `&` only the first one starts with a `?`

try this:

> `https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/${userId}/messages?access_token=${accessToken}&q=${text}